# Python3 breaking valid Python2 code: How can I send a series of bytes in a buffer in a socket in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sockets, byte

Basic question, but if I have socket `s` and I want to do:

```
s.sendto(("\u001b" + 47 * "1"), (mysite.com, 80))
```

How can I do this without the `\u001b` being converted to `"ESC"` in Python3 and making my program not run? This works in Python2.

Comment: What is the final string supposed to look like?

Comment: It is supposed to be 48 bytes, the first byte being `\x1b` and the rest being all bytes of `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3 you need to encode the string explicitly

You can do this a couple ways, but this might be the easiest:

```
payload = bytes("\u001b" + 47 * "1", 'utf-8')
s.sendto(payload, (mysite.com, 80))
```

In this case, the arguments we are using are:

```
bytes(string, encoding[, errors]) -> bytes
```

If you wanted to use a list of integers instead, you could try the following:

```
# 27 == ord('\x1b')
# 49 == ord('1')
bytes([27] + [49] * 47)
# b'\x1b11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
```